# Simple question about curvature on planar curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, plane-curves

So, I am studying Differential Geometry in university and i was given the following definition:
\begin{equation*}
K(s) = ||\beta''(s)||
\end{equation*}
Where $\beta(s)$ is a parametrization of a curve such that $||\beta'(s)|| = 1, \forall s$, and where $K(s)$ denotates the curvature of the curve.

I was wondering if this result is ALWAYS valid, including for planar curves. I know that we can "associate" a signal to curvature in planar curves, but my teacher solved an [exercise involving a planar curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrOQN.jpg) purely through the definition above, and i began to wonder if i can always do it through definition, independent of the planar curve in study.

Thanks for all the help in advance guys,

Best regards.

Comment: The point is that for plane curves you can always declare $\mathbf T, \mathbf N$ to be a right-handed frame, rather than defining $\mathbf N$ to be in the direction of $\alpha''$.

Comment: Thanks Ted, i think i understood it. Does that mean that i should only calculate the signed curvature when i get asked to? This is, if im only asked to calculate the curvature of a planar curve i should just use the definition i presented and never think of signed curvature?

Comment: Well, signed curvature makes a difference when you want a theorem like $\int_C \kappa\,ds = \pm 2\pi$ for a simple closed curve. But most of the time you are going to be doing curves in space, not plane curves, so you shouldn't have to worry about it. You might also find my differential geometry text (free pdf linked in my profile) helpful.

Comment: Thanks once again, i'll check it out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, curvature is always defined thus. For plane curve there is a signed curvature, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Plane_curves, but it is defined in terms of the unsigned quantity.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So, basically, if I am asked to calculate the curvature of a planar curve i can always use the definition i presented. So, when should I define the curvature based on the T and N vectors (this is, when should I calculate the signed curvature instead of the normal curvature i presented). Thanks once again

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues I think that if it is unclear from context, you should ask and clarify.

Comment: Thank you, really helpfull.